# Can I change settings of a file in Java (e.g. disabling Windows 10 full screen optimisations, overriding high DPI scaling)?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Is this possible to do? I know how to find/edit attributes of a file but I want to recursively change a set of executables file settings (e.g. disable high dpi scaling, windows 10 full screen optimisations). I tried this batch code from superuser:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags \Layers" /V "path/to/exe" /T REG_SZ /D ~HIGHDPIAWARE /F
```

Can't seem to get that to work though

Thanks

Comment: There is no built in way of doing this, Java is not really meant to be used to fiddle with OS. If you want to fiddle around with Windows native stuff, you should look into PowerShell.

Comment: I am confused, you ask in the heading if it is possible to do with java, but then in the actual question you refer to batch code, which seems to be windows batch? you also tag java and batch-file?

Comment: Sorry for my vagueness, the application is written in Java, and by extension I was using java code to launch a window batch file in a bid to solve the problem.

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE].  What evidence do you have that it did not work?  Error codes?  Something doesn't behave as expected?